# Dnspy compilation error without editing the code

Tags: c#, .net, dnspy

The 'ConnectionState' exists in both  'System.Data.Common, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

```cs
bool flag2 = this.sqlite_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open;
            if (flag2)
            {
                this.sqlite_conn.Close();
                this.sqlite_conn.Open();
            }
```

Getting above error in this line of code while using dnspy.
Error code is CS0433 from main.cs

Comment: Btw, what are you trying to achieve by this line of code `this.sqlite_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open;`? Close the connection? I think this can not compile. What about `this.sqlite_conn.Close();`?

Comment: The error says, that the type `ConnectionState` is in two assemblies. Try specify assembly you want to use. I guess it can be `this.sqlite_conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open;`

Comment: Also you can check the compiler error description and solution in more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433)

Comment: Replaced  with System. Data•ConnectionState•Open; still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your project references and using statements and remove any unused ones.
2. Try to explicitly put the proper namespace in front of your enum, like:

   System.Data.ConnectionState.Open;